# Jetson Nano low CNN inference performance

Tags: keras, performance

I'm running what I believe is a pretty small CNN on an nVidia Jetson Nano with Jetpack 4.4.
[nVidia claims the Nano can run a ResNet-50 at 36fps](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetson-nano-dl-inference-benchmarks), so I expected my much smaller network to run at 30+ fps with ease.

Actually though, each forward pass takes 160-180ms, so I score 5-6 fps at best.

My CNN:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
lambda (Lambda)              (None, 210, 848, 3)       0
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 210, 282, 3)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 102, 138, 16)      2368
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 51, 69, 16)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 33, 32)        12832
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 12, 16, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 4, 6, 64)          51264
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 2, 3, 64)          0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 384)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 384)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 64)                24640
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0
_________________________________________________________________
elu (ELU)                    (None, 64)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 65
=================================================================
Total params: 91,169
Trainable params: 91,169
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

model_name = 'v9_small_FC_epoch_3'
loaded_model = keras.models.load_model('/home/jetson/notebooks/trained_models/' + model_name + '.h5')
loaded_model.summary()
frame = cv2.imread('/home/jetson/notebooks/frame1.jpg')    
test_data = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)

for i in range(10):
    start = time.time()
    predictions = loaded_model.predict(test_data)
    print(predictions[0][0])
    end = time.time()
    print("Inference took {}s".format(end-start))
```

Result:

```
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 10.111131191253662s
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 0.1822071075439453s
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 0.17330455780029297s
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 0.18085694313049316s
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 0.16646790504455566s
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 0.1703803539276123s
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 0.1788337230682373s
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 0.17131853103637695s
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 0.1660606861114502s
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 0.18377089500427246s
```

Comment: I'm not sure what application you have in mind, but it would be **much faster** to load multiple images and predict them as a batch, not one by one.

Comment: That's not possible, it has to predict real-time on a camera feed. The benchmark figures given by nVidia are batchsize=1, too.

Comment: Maybe NVIDIA uses a different version of cuDNN? [Newer versions](https://developer.nvidia.com/CUDNN) are much more optimized.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for Stack Overflow (or Data Science SE). Here, we focus on the theoretical aspects of artificial intelligence (so this excludes hardware and software issues). Take a look at https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for mroe details about our site.

Comment: @nbro What's the correct way to open the same question over there? Copy/Paste and delete this one?

Comment: @couka Yes, alternatively, I can migrate it to there, but it will be shown as "migrated from AI SE". As you prefer. Let me know.

Comment: @nbro If you could do that, that would be great, thanks.

Comment: I will migrate this to Stack Overflow then, given SO has a bigger community. If you don't get an answer there after a while, you could try to re-ask the question on DS SE.